# How to put PDF picture in a fixed place relative to text

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, header-footer, diagrams

How to put PDF picture in background of header,chapter and section in a fixed place relative to text but with any affect to text flow.

Can I do this without using `Tikz`. because I heard it is slowing document compiling.

Comment: `tikzpicture` with options `remember picture` and `overlay`. See TikZ & PGF manula (v 3.1.9a), section *17.13.1 Referencing a Node in a Different Picture*, page 259.

Comment: You can use `eso-pic`  to add an existing picture to a given page with its `\AddtoShipoutPictureBG*` command.

Comment: @Zarko How to make horizntal postion relative to page center and vertical position relatve to the text?

Comment: @hubaishan Could you add a manual example of what you need, please?